# Play! 2.0.1 - css in assets

Tags: playframework-2.0, playframework

Underneath the `app` directory, I can reference a javascript file, `ajavascriptfile.js`, inside of a package, from an html document:

```
<script src="/assets/css/test/ajavascriptfile.js"></script>
```

[image]

However, I **can't** reference the css file, `acssfile.css`, inside of an html document:

```
<script src="/assets/css/test/acssfile.css"></script>
```

No error is thrown except in the console, which states the file is not found.  Is there a route I'm missing? For organization, it just seems makes sense to use packages to manage them, as opposed to the public folders (where I'm putting 3rd party files).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

H.Buzz is right, the way assets work in Play 2.0, you need to put your static assets in `public/`, not `app/assets/`. Out of the box, the only files in `app/assets/` that are being handled by Play are those ending in `.js`, `.coffee` or `.less`.

Your JavaScript file is being copied as part of its being compiled by the Google Closure Compiler. For CSS files there is no equivalent processing, so it does not get copied.

You need to either put the file into `public/` or extend Play's asset handling.

Comment: That's a bummer! I'm assuming if I ported the `.sass` plugin from 1.2.4 to 2.0.x, than I could use the package management?

Answer (score 0):

1. check file

{projectfolder}/**public**/css/test/acssfile.css

1. edit code

link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="@routes.Assets.at("css/test/acssfile.css")">

:)

Comment: Did you read the question? **For organization, it just seems makes sense to use packages to manage them, as opposed to the public folders (where I'm putting 3rd party files)**